# Upgrade simple show/hide jQuery: show first content + bold nav item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since I'm at the very beginning of learning jquery, I was hoping that someone could help me solve this: I have a code that hides/shows content when a nav-item is selected. The selected nav-item is also set to be bold.

Now I'd like to upgrade it so that:

**a.)** *the first content (menu_apps) is visible before any nav-item is selected*

**b.)** *the corresponding first nav-item (show_apps) is set to bold, so people can see that it is linked to the visible content.*

I've been trying to get it to work, but failed every time. Really curious to see the solution. Thanks for your time!

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/KUtY5/489/

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav a").click(function(){
       $("#nav a").css("font-weight", 400); // First you make them thin
       $(this).css("font-weight", 800); // Than you make them bold
           var id =  $(this).attr('id');
       id = id.split('_');
       $("#menu_container div").hide(); 
       $("#menu_container #menu_"+id[1]).show();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#menu_container {
 width: 650px;
 height: auto;
 padding-left: 30px;
}
#menu_container div {
 display:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='nav'>
    <a id="show_apps">Appetizers</a> | <a id="show_soups">Soups and Salads</a> | <a id="show_entrees">Entrees</a>
</div>

<div id="menu_container">
    <div id="menu_apps">
    Content of the App Section Here
    </div>
    <div id="menu_soups">
    Content of the Soups Section Here
    </div>
    <div id="menu_entrees">
    Content of the Entrees Section Here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have much to add to the other answers, but I would suggest in general that you define some CSS classes and add/remove those, rather than programmatically changing individual style properties with `css()`. By marking elements with classes, you not only change their look, but also gain a way to select and operate on them programmatically elsewhere in the script with jQuery selectors. For example, in a table with multiple selected rows, you could get a list of those rows by using `$('tr.highlighted')` where `highlighted` is the name of the CSS class that made them look selected.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful advice @zerobandwith :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have updated your code little bit check it out 
http://jsfiddle.net/KUtY5/493/
I have added these lines on your document ready

```
$("#menu_apps").show();
$("#show_apps").css("font-weight", 400); // First you make them thin
$('#show_apps').css("font-weight", 800);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ahmed! Have a great day ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#nav a").click(function(){
 $("#nav a").css("font-weight", 400); // First you make them thin
 $(this).css("font-weight", 800); // Than you make them bold
  var id =  $(this).attr('id');
  id = id.split('_');
  $("#menu_container div").hide(); 
    $("#menu_container #menu_"+id[1]).show();
 });
    $("#nav a:first").css("font-weight", 800);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you.. Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#menu_container div").hide(); 
$("#menu_container #menu_"+'apps').show();
$("#show_apps").css("font-weight", 800);

   $("#nav a").click(function(){
     $("#nav a").css("font-weight", 400); // First you make them thin
      $(this).css("font-weight", 800); // Than you make them bold
            var id =  $(this).attr('id');
      id = id.split('_');
      $("#menu_container div").hide(); 
      $("#menu_container #menu_"+id[1]).show();
   });
});
```

```css
#menu_container{
  width: 650px;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#menu_container div{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='nav'>
        <a id="show_apps">Appetizers</a> | <a id="show_soups">Soups and Salads</a> | <a id="show_entrees">Entrees</a>
    </div>
  
  
<div id="menu_container">
  <div id="menu_apps">
    Content of the App Section Here
  </div>
  <div id="menu_soups">
    Content of the Soups Section Here
  </div>
  <div id="menu_entrees">
    Content of the Entrees Section Here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Renuka! Have a great day ahead :)